# LINQ - Where a list contains an element of another list

Tags: linq, entity-framework, where-clause

I have two SQL tables: `Movies` and `Tags`, while `Movies` contains a `List<Tag>`

Now I want to find all movies that have at least one of the tags of a `List<Tag>` argument.  How can I do that in LINQ?

```
public IEnumerable<Group<Genre, Movie>> GetMoviesGrouped(string search, List<Tag> tags)
{
    var movies = from movie in Movies
    where ( movie.Name.Contains(search)) && movie.Tags.???contains any element of tags???
    group movie by movie.genre into g
    select new Group<Genre, Movie> { Key = g.Key, Values = g };
....
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Movies where any of the tags is contains in `tags`:

```
var movies = from movie in Movies
             where ( movie.Name.Contains(search)) 
                  && movie.Tags.Any(t => tags.Contains(t))
             group movie by movie.genre into g
             select new Group<Genre, Movie> { Key = g.Key, Values = g };
```

However since this is comparing `Tag` instances and not strings:

1. It probably won't get translated to SQL (which means you will have to hydrate the query and do the extra filtering in Linq-to-Objects), and
2. You may want to compare the *data* of the tags rather than *instances* (unless you have overridden `Equals` on `Tag`

something like:

```
where movie.Tags.Any(mt => tags.Any(t => t.ID == mt.ID))   // or whatever property(ies) of `Tag` defines equality
```

Answer (score 2):

You can intersect both list and see if there is any element like:

```
&& movie.Tags.Intersect(tags).Any()
```

Since `Tag` is an object, It will compare the references. Instead you can select unique identifier from  `Tag` and then intersect that like:

```
&& movie.Tags.Select(r=> r.ID).Intersect(tags.Select(t=> t.ID)).Any()
```

Where `ID` is the primary key of `Tag` table.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, do you mean it doesn't get translated into SQL ?

Comment: `Tag` is not a string, i assume you need an `IEqualityComparer` here or overridden `Equals` and `GetHashCode`s.